# How can I change the link "add to cart" button?

Tags: php, jquery, joomla

When i click on the "add to cart" (button) , i want it to be directed to my own products page ,which i've created it with gallery Component ,it goes to virtuemart while, as i said it should be directed to my own product page

[site example](http://demo.hotjoomlatemplates.com/index.php?template=watches)

(components/com_virtuemart/views/productdetails/tmpl/default_addtocart.php)

```
<span class="addtocart-button">
<?php echo shopFunctionsF::getAddToCartButton ($this->product->orderable);
  // Display the add to cart button END  ?>
```

something similar to that.

```
<a href="yourwebsite.com/thelinkyouwanthere.php">Buy Product</a>

<span class="addtocart-button">
<a href="yourwebsite.com/thelinkyouwanthere.php">Buy Product</a>
```

Function:getAddToCartButton

```
    static public function getAddToCartButton($orderable){

    if($orderable){
        vmJsApi::jPrice();
        $html = '<input type="submit" name="addtocart" class="addtocart-button" value="'.JText::_('COM_VIRTUEMART_CART_ADD_TO') .'" title="'.JText::_('COM_VIRTUEMART_CART_ADD_TO') .'" />';
    } else {
        $html = '<input name="addtocart" class="addtocart-button-disabled" value="'.JText::_('COM_VIRTUEMART_ADDTOCART_CHOOSE_VARIANT') .'" title="'.JText::_('COM_VIRTUEMART_ADDTOCART_CHOOSE_VARIANT') .'" />';
    }

    return $html;
}
```

**But my problem is that the address is different for each product with other products**

[Image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/32nt6ox088t2znd/Capture.JPG)

Thank you

Comment: What is the body of shopFunctionsF::getAddToCartButton?

Comment: The question was edited.

Comment: I guess I'm still not seeing the issue you're talking about. The form seems to be directing to index.php?

Answer (score 0):

Use template overrides: [How to override the output from the Joomla! core](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core)

On your example you should add this file on your template:

```
templates/your_template/html/com_virtuemart/productdetails/default_addtocart.php
```

where `your_template` is the directory of the template your are using.

A good starting point is to copy the original final and then edit according to your needs. In general you should avoid the modification of the original files, because you may lost your changes when you update the extension.